# Create enumerate like indented nesting environment

Tags: listings, indentation

I want to create an environment that will have indentation to all the content inside it. Similar to `\begin{enumberate}- \end{enumerate}` but without need of writing `\item`

I tried doing it like this

```
\newenvironment{indented}
{\par\leftskip1cm\relax}
{\par\leftskip0cm\relax}
```

This works partially with 2 problems -

1. Nesting doesn't work.
2. Code listing using `lstlisting` doesn't honor this.

Please suggest how to make this work.

Comment: Nesting can be done with `\newenvironment{indented}
{\par\leftskip=\dimexpr\leftskip+1cm\relax}
{\par\leftskip=\dimexpr\leftskip-1cm\relax}`.  However, it will not address the `lstlisting` issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes why not `\advance\leftskip 1cm\relax`?

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for the more efficient syntax.  My plain TeX skills are somewhat rudimentary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage) is an environment that allows you to adjust the left and right margin. Here's a simple implementation (using the base code from [Niranjan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627984/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\newenvironment{enumlike}[1][15pt]{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{0pt}% Only indent on left side
}{%
  \end{adjustwidth}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumlike}

  \begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/usr
echo "hello world"
  \end{lstlisting}
  
  abcd efgh

  abcd efgh
  \begin{enumlike}[20pt]
    \begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/usr
echo "hello world"
    \end{lstlisting}

    pqrs wxyz
    
    pqrs wxyz
  \end{enumlike}
\end{enumlike}

\end{document}
```

Note that `15pt` - the default optional argument for `enumlike` - is the default `\parindent`, which could make things line up coincidently. Of course, this can be changed.

Comment: Hmm, this is even better :)

Comment: This works great, but is not able to handle float environments like `\begin{table}-\end{table}` and `\begin{figure}-\end{figure}`, can we modify it to support these float environments.

Comment: @aaryan: Floats *float*, which means they would not stay within the scope of the width changes. If you want that to occur, try with `\begin{figure}[H]` and `\begin{table}[H]` (you'll need to add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble).

Comment: @Werner Yes, I am not talking about floating of the floats. When I use `[H]` they stay in place but the width is not affected by the parent enumlike environment. The table starts from the left margin of the page which I don't want. It should start from the most recent indentation.

Comment: @aaryan: Floats use a different setup, and specifically set their content inside a box of width `\columnwidth`, not `\linewidth`. Apart from that, horizontal alignment in also set differently. I'd suggest asking a new ([follow-up](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)) question.

Comment: @Werner I have added a follow-up question [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629851/indenting-the-table-and-figure-environments/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use the `quote` environment instead?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newenvironment{enumlike}{%
  \begin{quote}%
  }{%
  \end{quote}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumlike}
  \begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/usr
echo "hello world"
  \end{lstlisting}
  
  abcd efgh

  abcd efgh
  \begin{enumlike}
    \begin{lstlisting}
#!/bin/usr
echo "hello world"
    \end{lstlisting}

    pqrs wxyz
    
    pqrs wxyz
  \end{enumlike}
\end{enumlike}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: But `quote` indents at both sides.

Comment: Right, my bad. Werner's solution is better.